# What is a good ASP.NET MVC detailed error page example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, error-handling

I looked through a bunch of other questions looking for an awesome example of a detailed error page layout and did not find anything.  I am sure many people have made this before.

Requirements
 * Must show exception information (type, stack trace)
 * Should show form values if possible
 * Should show what area/controller/action caused the issue

The best I have come up with is:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{ViewBag.Title = "Error";}

<h2>Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
<p>Please copy and paste this entire page in an email to 
<a href="mailto:me@me.com?subject=Website%20Error">Me</a> 
along with any other information you can provide so we can
get this fixed ASAP!</p>
@if (Model != null) {
    <h1>@Model.Exception.GetType().Name<br />
        thrown in @Model.ControllerName @Model.ActionName</h1>

    <h2>Details</h2>
    <div>
        @Model.Exception.ToString()
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why ask them to email you the error, many people including myself would never send you an email. Use something like ELMAH to automatically email you on unhandled exceptions and display a friendly error page.

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

If you want to get feedback from your users when an error occurs, you can have a textbox and ask them to give you information as to what they were doing when they landed on the error page, this does seem to work well, it shows that you're being pro-active in trying to solve the solution. Be sure to say something to let them know that you have been notified, but you're looking for additional information to keep the error from happening again in the future

Comment: And that is why I love StackOverflow.